# What will happen if the N region in a PNP transistor is replaced with metal?

Tags: transistors

I came across this question when I appeared for an interview at one of the IITs for my PhD course.

The interviewer also asked me to draw the I-V characteristic of the modified device. I asked this of many of my technical friends but all of them failed to convince me with the answer.

What I learned was that there will be some Schottky contact developed between metal and semiconductor.

Will the new device be still called a transistor?

Any reference or research paper link would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you found after doing your own search? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I found that there will be a schottky contact developed on both the junctions. I am unable to draw Current-volatge characteristics